# Why do all my radio buttons share a single selection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a survey app and I've hit a roadblock. When I'm submitting a response to a survey, all my answers share the same radio button selection id which means that I can **only select one radio button across multiple questions** whereas I want this to be one radio button *per* question.

I'm baffled and would very much appreciate some help.

I'm using simple_form for this project.

### views/responses/_form.html.erb

```
<%= @response %>
<%= @response.survey_id %>

<%= @survey.name %>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @survey.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>End date:</strong>
  <%= @survey.end_date %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= simple_form_for [@survey, @response] do |f| %>
    <!-- Survey id -->
    <%= f.hidden_field :survey_id, :value => @survey.id %>

      <!-- Questions -->
      <ol>
        <% @survey.questions.each do |q| %>
          <li><%= q.content %></li>

          <!-- Iterate through answers for this question -->
          <%= f.simple_fields_for :answers do |a| %>
            <%= f.association :answers, collection: q.answers, as: :radio_buttons, :item_wrapper_class => 'test_class', include_blank: false %>
          <% end %>

        <% end %>
      </ol>


    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

### Models

### survey.rb

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :responses

  validates_presence_of :name
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
end
```

### question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey, optional: true
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

### answer.rb

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question, optional: true
  belongs_to :response, optional: true

  def to_label
    "#{content}"
  end
end
```

### response.rb

```
class Response < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey, optional: true
  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Thanks,
Bhams

Edit:

### Generated HTML

```
<p>
  <form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_response" id="new_response" action="/surveys/9/responses" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="39QorGeTDhu7pojy3L6gbZ1GZh9yBhqZphFMRWD++Ghd2ScWeLVEcdyhD9Ym0JyKHLptghvLOnJP9UlmHn32Bw==" />
    <!-- Survey id -->
    <input value="9" type="hidden" name="response[survey_id]" id="response_survey_id" />

      <!-- Questions -->
      <ol>
          <li>222</li>

          <!-- Iterate through answers for this question -->

            <div class="input radio_buttons optional response_answers"><label class="radio_buttons optional">Answers</label><input type="hidden" name="response[answer_ids]" value="" /><span class="radio test_class"><label for="response_answer_ids_35"><input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="35" name="response[answer_ids]" id="response_answer_ids_35" />11111</label></span><span class="radio test_class"><label for="response_answer_ids_36"><input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="36" name="response[answer_ids]" id="response_answer_ids_36" />2222</label></span><span class="radio test_class"><label for="response_answer_ids_37"><input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="37" name="response[answer_ids]" id="response_answer_ids_37" />33333</label></span><span class="radio test_class"><label for="response_answer_ids_38"><input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="38" name="response[answer_ids]" id="response_answer_ids_38" />444444</label></span><span class="radio test_class"><label for="response_answer_ids_39"><input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="39" name="response[answer_ids]" id="response_answer_ids_39" />55555</label></span></div>

          <li>33333333333</li>

          <!-- Iterate through answers for this question -->

            <div class="input radio_buttons optional response_answers"><label class="radio_buttons optional">Answers</label><input type="hidden" name="response[answer_ids]" value="" /><span class="radio test_class"><label for="response_answer_ids_40"><input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="40" name="response[answer_ids]" id="response_answer_ids_40" />4444444444444</label></span><span class="radio test_class"><label for="response_answer_ids_41"><input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="41" name="response[answer_ids]" id="response_answer_ids_41" />55555</label></span></div>

      </ol>


    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Response" data-disable-with="Create Response" />
</form></p>
```

Comment: Can you add the generated html for the problematic radio buttons please?

Comment: @sokkyoku : Ok, added.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.association :answers, collection: q.answers, as: :radio_buttons
```

Generates a radio element for each element in q.answers with the name "response[answer_ids]".
The name attribute on radio elements is what defines them as belonging to the same group inside a form.

In the generated code, all of your radio inputs have `name="response[answer_ids]"` so they are all mutually exclusive.

You need to have different `name` values for each question. How you do this is your choice.

Comment: The association is for response.answers. The variable 'q' is simply for iterating through the questions that exist in survey. Thus doing f.association q.name doesn't work.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify the variable 'q' is from @survey.questions.